# Flexdashboard CSS not correct

Tags: flexdashboard

I was previously using R 3.3.2 and had built a Flexdashboard that worked fine, but after upgrading to R 3.4 somehow the CSS for the output html file is all wrong for some reason. There aren't any error messages when rendering and I can't figure out what's causing the issue. I've tried updating *rmarkdown* and *flexdashboard* to the latest CRAN versions.

Here's what it looked like before:
[Default styles applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECvvm.png)

Here's what it looks like now:
[No styling and content visibility is set to hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uslJy.png)

I can also replicate it with a minimal example:

```
---
title: "Test Markdown"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

### This is a header
This is some text
```

I run it using:

```
rmarkdown::render("TestMD.Rmd")
```

Here's what I get from `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4        backports_1.1.2       magrittr_1.5          
rprojroot_1.3-2       htmltools_0.3.6       tools_3.4.4          
 [7] flexdashboard_0.5.1.1 yaml_2.1.18           Rcpp_0.12.16          stringi_1.1.7         rmarkdown_1.10        knitr_1.20           
[13] jsonlite_1.5          stringr_1.3.0         digest_0.6.15         evaluate_0.10.1
```

And the minimum example looks like this:
[No styles again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmQup.png)